# Fallo de validacion de xml en SPRING

Tags: xml, spring

Estoy tratando de añadir una referencia a una ruta pero al añadirlo me da fallo la validacion en el IDE[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me responde esto en consola:

```
XML validation started.
Checking file:/home/emendez/NetBeansProjects/HorarioSpring/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-servlet.xml...
Referenced entity at "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd".
Referenced entity at "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd".
Referenced entity at "http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.0.xsd".
El prefijo "mvc" para el elemento "mvc:resources" no está enlazado. [22] 
XML validation finished.
```

¿Sabeis por que puede ser?

Answer (score 0):

Los prefijos indican un esquema que se ha cargado previamente, y que define los elementos XML.

En este caso, buscando por [`spring mvc schema`](https://www.google.es/search?q=spring+mvc+schema&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=SXyqWpItjrJfleSnoAY) te devuelve rápidamente la información de qué esquemas te faltan (p.ej [esta página](https://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-spring-mvc-form-annotation-config-webapp-spring-config.html)).

En resumen, a `xsi:schemaLocation` debes añadir

```
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc                  <--
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd"> <--
```